# Reuse definitions in Swagger

Tags: c#, .net-core, swagger, swashbuckle

How can I reuse Swagger definition of parameters that appear repetitively in multiple endpoints without modifying JSON directly. I saw answers that do it through JSON, but how can I change XML in code file to generate such JSON with global sections. Talking specifically about .NET core code file.
For concrete models documentation is reused automatically using $ref, but I want to reuse definitions for primitive types as well. 
In my case there are set of endpoints with similar parameters. 
Ex-

```
/// <summary>     
/// </summary>
/// <param name="monthKey">Month in MM format.</param>
/// <param name="userType">Type of user - In house or external or trial user</param>
public void getProductsForMonth(string monthKey, string userType)
/// <summary>     
/// </summary>
/// <param name="userType">Type of user - In house or external or trial user</param>
public void getAllProductsOfType(string userType)
```

here parameter usertype is repeated and I need to repeat definition for both endpoints in the code. Is there a way to specify in my C# file that I can reuse the parameter definition from other endpoint.

Comment: can you provide some sample scenarios you are thinking about

Comment: The Swagger definition of parameters should be just a reflection of your code, maybe the models in your code are repetitive

Comment: updated the question with code samples

Comment: not sure what could be reused on that code sample, usertype is a string parameter it should show twice in swagger just like it does in your code